# Unable to get all foodpanda shop names using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

As i print only one shop name i want to extract all shop names from  https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants
i want to get all shops names help me please

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver

url= "https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
pageSource = driver.page_source
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1



"""last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

this doesn't work due to floating web elements on youtube
"""

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
conte = None

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height and conte:
       
       break
       
    last_height = new_height
    time.sleep(5)
    pageSource = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
    conte = soup.find_all('ul',class_='vendor-list') 
    
for items in conte:
    ptitle= items.find('span',class_='name fn').text

print(ptitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome( options=options)
driver.get(url)


[print(i.text) for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    ".vendor-list .headline .name")]
```

you don't need beautiful soap , just call the headline element and print text from it

Comment: Thanks and if i want to scrape price also what method sholud i apply

Comment: Same method check for the price element

Comment: please help it create  problem when i add delivery it give me error please solved this

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the request the page makes to get the all the data including the restuarant names. This way you don't need the overhead of a browser.

```
import requests, json

headers = {'x-disco-client-id': 'web'}

params = (
    ('latitude', '24.9414896'),
    ('longitude', '67.1676002'),
    ('language_id', '1'),
    ('include', 'characteristics'),
    ('new_sorting', 'true'),
    ('dynamic_pricing', '0'),
    ('configuration', 'Variant3'),
    ('country', 'pk'),
    ('customer_id', ''),
    ('customer_hash', ''),
    ('budgets', ''),
    ('cuisine', ''),
    ('sort', ''),
    ('food_characteristic', ''),
    ('use_free_delivery_label', 'false'),
    ('vertical', 'restaurants'),
    ('limit', '1000'),
    ('offset', '0'),
    ('customer_type', 'regular'),
)

r = requests.get('https://disco.deliveryhero.io/listing/api/v1/pandora/vendors', headers=headers, params=params)
data = json.loads(r.text)['data']
restuarants = {i['name'] for i in data['items']}
print(restuarants)
```